# TextToSpeech - Unable to start activity: findViewById(R.id.srcText) must not be null in Kotlin Android

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, null, findviewbyid

Been working on a real-time Translation project combined with TTS, but I'm a total beginner in Android development. The OCR and translate functions are working properly since I referred to the [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/mlkit-android-translate#1).

However, after I have added TTS to MainActivity with **srcText(TextView) in main_fragment.xml** the error showed up. Have read a number of posts regarding this problem, but can't seem to find a suitable solution since the structure of the project files from the codelab is quite complicated(activity, fragment, ViewModel...) .

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate.main.MainFragment
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {


    private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null //ADDED from TextToSpeech

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) //Changed



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }

        
        //TextToSpeech starts here...
        //(Copied code) Button and etEnteredText need to be removed and modified respectively
        tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)
        //val btnSpeak: Button =findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak)
        //val etEnteredText: EditText =findViewById(R.id.etEnteredText)

        Log.i("123","Initialization Completed")

        val srcText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.srcText)
        val translatedText: TextView= findViewById(R.id.translatedText)
        //btnSpeak.setOnClickListener{ view ->

            if(srcText.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    "Enter a text to use TTS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }else{
                speakOut(srcText.text.toString())
            }

            //Do the same for ...

            if(translatedText.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    "Enter a text to use TTS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }else{
                speakOut(translatedText.text.toString())
            }

        //}
    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // set US English as language for tts
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS","The Language specified is not supported!")
            }


        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed!")
        }

    }

    private fun speakOut(text: String){
        tts!!.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
    }

    public override fun onDestroy() {

        if (tts != null) {
            tts!!.stop()
            tts!!.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }


}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

main_fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.google.mlkit.showcase.translate.main.MainFragment">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/middle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/viewfinder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/viewfinder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewfinder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/viewfinder" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/srcLang"
        style="@style/SrcLangText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/srcTextScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/middle"
        tools:text="source lang" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/srcTextScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/srcLang">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/srcText"
            style="@style/SrcText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            tools:text="source text" />
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/targetLangSelector"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/srcTextScrollView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/targetLangSelector"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/translatedTextScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/targetLangSelector">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/translatedText"
            style="@style/TranslatedText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            tools:text="translated text" />
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/translatedTextScrollView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_google_translate_attribution"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/greyscale_regular_3x"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/targetLangSelector"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/targetLangSelector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/targetLangSelector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/downloading_model_files"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/progressBar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat Error Message

```
2022-05-12 02:49:48.730 18411-18411/com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate, PID: 18411
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate/com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.srcText) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.srcText) must not be null
        at com.google.mlkit.codelab.translate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Need a helping hand from my fellow developers and hopefully without making a whole lot of changes to the original structure. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this it might be Work :**

```
private var srcText : TextView ? = null //Add this variable above onCreate
```

**Find view by ID. Within on Create**

```
srcText = findViewById(R.id.srcText)
```

So Your onCreate Code is like this :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) //Changed



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }

        
        //TextToSpeech starts here...
        //(Copied code) Button and etEnteredText need to be removed and modified respectively
        tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)
        //val btnSpeak: Button =findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak)
        //val etEnteredText: EditText =findViewById(R.id.etEnteredText)

        Log.i("123","Initialization Completed")

        srcText = findViewById(R.id.srcText)  // Find View By ID of srcText Here


        val translatedText: TextView= findViewById(R.id.translatedText)
        //btnSpeak.setOnClickListener{ view ->

            if(srcText.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    "Enter a text to use TTS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }else{
                speakOut(srcText.text.toString())
            }

            //Do the same for ...

            if(translatedText.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    "Enter a text to use TTS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }else{
                speakOut(translatedText.text.toString())
            }

        //}
    }
```

Hope this Will work.